# use of globalstorage is deprecated. please use localstorage instead

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I got this message when doing some javascript programming, and after some google searches, I have no idea what it means, or how i cause this error.  I'm including the code below, can someone explain it to me or point me to a resource on how to fix it or what is happening at all?  The weird thing is that I have other code just like this part in my program, and it never gives me errors about them, so i'm really confused.  Also, I only get this error to display with firebug running, else wise it just doesn't work and no error message is displayed.  I also tried it in Chrome, and had the same issues, no error message but the code doesn't work.

```
foundTextFn = function(){
console.log('fire');
if (foundTextArrayPosition != foundTextArray.length){
    writeText(foundTextArray[foundTextArrayPosition],"happy");                      
    foundTextArrayPosition += 1;
  }
  foundTextFnTimer=setTimeout("foundTextFn()",4000);
}
```

Here is another of my methods, it is basically the same thing, but it works fine.  And if it matters, all of these variables are global variables declared at the start of my file as var foundTextArrayPosition = 0;  for example.

```
awayFn = function(){
if (awayArrayPosition != awayArray.length){
        if (changeAwayState){
            changeAwayState = false;
            writeText(awayArray[awayArrayPosition],"normal");
            awayArrayPosition ++;
            temp = pickRandomSpot();
            randomX = temp[0];
            randomY = temp[1];
        }
        else{
            changeAwayState = true;
        }
        awayTimer=setTimeout("awayFn()",10000);
    }
else{
    abandoned = true;
    whyGoneArrayPosition = 0;
    whyGoneFn();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using localStorage?

Comment: What kind of storage am I using now?

Comment: Have you read the error message at all?

Comment: So by default you use global storage I guess, I'm new to JavaScript so I didn't really understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a deprecation error in Firefox 9. `globalstorage` was a way to store data in Firefox, but HTML5 introduced `localstorage`, which is now the preferred way (using `window.localStorage`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage has more information.

Comment: So why did this error happen now? I have a bunch of variables defined in my js file, but i never get this error.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? What libraries are you using?

Comment: My code is around 600 lines, so I don't think that will help.  But I'll post another one of my methods that, as far as I can tell, is all but the same as this method but works.  And the only library I'm using is KineticJS.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but I maybe know what is up.  I've used up the global space (or something like that) so i should use local storage.  Use instead of saying var HEIGHT = 800;  and should say sessionStorage.HEIGHT=800;  am I on the right track here?

Comment: No, it's not the variables you're using, it's a browser storage you're using. I don't think you've used up the global space -- my guess is that you're using a library call that stores to globalStorage. Can you search your entire code base for the line globalStorage?

Comment: I checked, but my code and the KineticJS code library does not call globalStorage, or anything like it.

Comment: How about sessionStorage? That uses globalStorage as well.

Comment: i searched for the word 'storage' across all the code and did not find anything.  The only thing I found is Kinetic.GlobalObject, but I don't think that has any connection.

Comment: Ok so, I have no idea how, but I'm not getting the error again.  There were a few bugs in my code related to some variable resets, maybe that effect it.  But either way the error is gone now.  I wish i knew why though, I'll read up on all this storage stuff.  But thanks for all you help a ton!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message and found a solution and perhaps the underlying cause of conflict, I was using the jQuery validate function in the jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js library along with jQuery 1.7.1

The problem: 
I used `$(document)`.ready with two different `contexts`.  One with the `noConflict` wrapper and one without.  By keeping both the same, the error message went away.  Hooray!

The wrapper:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
$(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() { ...}

});
});
```

See also [this post](http://webcitymaster.com/conflicts-with-jquery-noconflict-wrapper/) on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not related to the issue above but I will put it here for the search engines.

I got the same error message while doing some simple jQuery:

```
Use of globalStorage is deprecated. Please use localStorage instead.
[Break On This Error]   

$(document).ready(function() {
```

It was however due to forgetting to actually include the link href to the jQuery.js file...!